# A text doesn't shows in under of a div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

https://play.tailwindcss.com/0ZTC5qOVe2

So, I create a two div for a website thing, and this is what happen:
[image: failed mobile text]
but when we swapped it into a bigger area, the text is not overwritten the div:
[image: good desktop text]

I'm tried it with an legacy thing, yep it is `<br>`, but I wont use it because i want to create an responsive website, I tried everything and it is not worked.

I'm expecting to the div/text does not overwritten on the first div, it should be under it. using a desktop is works, but mobile isn't.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

Add the following css code to your div:

```
z-index:99;
```

Thats all, it is very simple to fix